# Why is "tar" trying to create an empty archive?

Tags: linux, backup, file-transfer, tar

I'm trying to use tar to tar files before transfer, so I can keep the entire file path rather than losing it along the way. However, when I try to tar an empty folder, it tells me that it is cowardly refusing to create an empty archive. I want to keep the empty folder on the other end, but don't want to put anything else into the archive to make it non-empty. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Works fine here. How are you doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What command are you using? I am able to create a tar archive of an empty directory just fine:

```
[jnet@Stan tmp]$ mkdir test
[jnet@Stan tmp]$ tar -cf test.tar test
[jnet@Stan tmp]$ ls -lh test.tar 
-rw-r--r--  1 jnet  wheel    10K Apr 20 21:58 test.tar
```

Comment: Looking at your answer, I realized I forgot the first argument... so this is really just an ID10T error.

Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: You know it's cowardly to create an empty archive right? ;-)

Comment: @josh: i'm pretty sure it was the *refusal to create an empty archive* that was "cowardly".  tho i'm not remembering who says that.  is that a *tar* error or somebody else?

Comment: snostorm@ubuntu:~$ tar -cf filename
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: So that's a tar error. :)

Comment: @quack quixo: Yeah, you're right, my joke didn't make too much sense... I tried! :-)