# How to get an empty tar archive?

Tags: tar

I am making an RPM in which everything is contained in the .spec file (don't ask :-).  rpmbuild requires a "Source" file, so I was trying to create an empty tar file.  However, if I don't give any filenames, tar complains:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

How do I create a truly empty tar file?

Comment: its been answered before here:  http://superuser.com/questions/133186/forcing-tar-to-create-an-empty-archive

Comment: Actually, @Rhuyuk, it hasn't.  That post is someone who forgot to list a filename, and the answer helped them realize they needed to pass another argument, resulting in a non-empty archive.  This is why I changed the title of that question, and created this question, which *DOES* answer what the title of that question was asking.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can force GNU and BSD tar to create an empty archive with:

```
tar -cf tarfilename.tar -T /dev/null
```

Comment: ya, 'f' option must be last, as it specifies the filename.  You're going to create an archive named T, but it'll error on missing tarfilename.tar file anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, this was a typo above, I didn't mean to include the "-", without it GNU tar 1.26 works fine.  Others are probably better with the options split out, but I don't have a system with various tars on to test it with.

Comment: One reason to create an empty tar: scripted tar creation. Step 1: Create the tar. Step 2: Add files one by one. You can do this with an "if first file then create else then append" but that's not as smooth.

Comment: @dpk: If I understand what you are saying, why don't you just always use append?  Append will create the tar file if it doesn't already exist, so you don't need to check if it's the first file, just append and if it's the first file tar will create it.

Comment: @SeanReifschneider It looks like that'd work fine. Nice.

Comment: @SeanReifschneider: +1 for the hint that append mode creates the archive for the first file if it's not already on disk. I'm using find command to exec tar in append mode in a script so didn't need to create the archive file before-hand.

Answer (score 18):

## If you have GNU tar

Either using `/dev/null`

```
$ tar -cf empty.tar --files-from /dev/null
```

Or by reading EOF from standard input.

```
$ printf '' | tar -cf empty.tar --files-from -
```

## If you don't have tar

An empty tar file is just a file with 10240 NUL bytes in it. So to create an empty tar file, you don't even need `tar` but instead can use either of these:

```
$ head --bytes=10240 /dev/zero > empty.tar
$ truncate --size=10240 empty.tar
$ fallocate --length=10240 empty.tar
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=10240 count=1 iflag=fullblock > empty.tar
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=10240 > empty.tar
```

### Why does this work?

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

> Physically, an archive consists of a series of file entries terminated by an end-of-archive entry, which consists of two 512 blocks of zero bytes.
>
> At the end of the archive file there are two 512-byte blocks filled with binary zeros as an end-of-file marker.

So in practice, it's sufficient to write 1024 zero bytes (two times 512 byte blocks) into a file to obtain an empty archive:

```
$ head --bytes=1024 /dev/zero > empty.tar
$ tar tvf empty.tar
```

If we only write 1023 zeros and a single 'one' into a file, tar will complain because instead of two blocks filled with all zeros, it only found one block with all zeros (the first) while the second was not all zeros:

```
$ { head --bytes=1023 /dev/zero; printf '\001' } > empty.tar
$ tar tvf empty.tar
tar: A lone zero block at 1
```

But why not just 1024 zero bytes but 10240 instead? The reason is blocking or the default record size or the blocking factor:

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking-Factor.html

The default blocking factor is 20. With a block size of 512 bytes, we get a record size of 10240. And tar will always pad the tarball such that its size is a multiple of the record size:

> Some devices requires that all write operations be a multiple of a certain size, and so, tar pads the archive out to the next record boundary.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for your hints about dd usage! I learned something new! About answering the right question: The title indeed asks "how to force tar" but when reading the question text, it becomes clear, that OP actually wants an empty tar file and it should not matter how.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question.

Comment: "just a file with 10240 NUL bytes in it" source for that?

Comment: @Mr.Roland https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html "terminated by an end-of-archive entry, which consists of two 512 blocks of zero bytes" -- each block is 20 bytes and 512 times 20 is 10240

Comment: Or as empirical evidence: `tar --create --files-from /dev/null | wc -c` will give a file with 10240 zeros.

Comment: " two 512 blocks" if each block is 20 bytes this would be `2*512*20` which equals `20480`

Comment: @Mr.Roland then it seems we need to file a bug report against GNU tar because then the "empty tar" it outputs is faulty.

Comment: Maybe the doc is incorrect.

Comment: @Mr.Roland The docs are correct. I just read them wrongly. The only thing saving my dignity is the comment on top of the "blocking" chapter: "Block and record terminology is rather confused, and it is also confusing to the expert reader." As a result I updated my answer with what I learned.

Answer (score 10):

BSD: `tar cvf empty.tar --from-file /dev/null`

GNU (Linux): `tar cvf empty.tar --files-from /dev/null`

Solaris: `tar cvf empty.tar -I /dev/null`

Comment: Finally something that works in Solaris!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create an empty archive by archiving a single file, then deleting the file from the archive.

```
tar cf empty.tar somefile                   # creates archive
tar --delete -f empty.tar somefile          # remove the file
tar tf empty.tar                            # list contents of archive
```

This works for me.

Comment: I can verify that with GNU tar this will produce the expected 10K file of all NUL characters.