# Bash Script not working as intended

Tags: linux, bash

So, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to scripting, like this is my first one.  I have created the following script:

```
# This simply declares which states we are using to create tarballs from
for blah in ar ky ms ny; 
do 
    # This will go into each tomcat-state directory and create a tarball in /home/ec-user for all files older than 90 days
    find /var/www/apps/tomcat-${blah}/logs -type f -mtime +90 | xargs tar -cvzf /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar.gz; 

    # This creates a master archive tarball containing all the archive-state.tar.gz files
    tar -cvzf /home/ec2-user/ebd-log-archives.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar;

    # Since in step one, we archives all files older than 90 days, this step removes them.
    # find /var/www/apps/tomcat-${blah}/logs -type f  -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;

    # And since we have the master archive file, this removes the archive-state files
    rm /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar.gz;
done
```

I have commented out the deleting of the logs for testing.

The problem is, when I get the master tarball, it only has NY in it, or whichever I put as my last in the loop (I tested this to make sure it wasn't just a odd NY thing)

Not sure what's going on, I tested it against an older script SIMILAR to this in wording on that server, and that one runs fine.

Edit: Thanks for the responses, I have updated the script to:

```
# This creates the master tarball we will be using
tar -cvzf /home/ec2-user/ebd-log-archives.tar.gz

# This simply declares which states we are using to create tarballs from
for blah in ar ky ms ny; 
do 
    # This will go into each tomcat-state directory and create a tarball in /home/ec-user for all files older than 90 days
    find /var/www/apps/tomcat-${blah}/logs -type f -mtime +90 | xargs tar -cvzf /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar.gz; 

    # This creates a master archive tarball containing all the archive-state.tar.gz files
    tar -rvzf /home/ec2-user/ebd-log-archives.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar;

    # Since in step one, we archives all files older than 90 days, this step removes them.
    # find /var/www/apps/tomcat-${blah}/logs -type f  -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;

    # And since we have the master archive file, this removes the archive-state files
    rm /home/ec2-user/archive-${blah}.tar.gz;
done
```

I'll try running with this and posting an update

Comment: Try without the semi-colon after the `ny`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run `tar -c`, the tool creates a new archive. If you tell it to use an existing name (`ebd-log-archives.tar.gz` in your case), the old archive will be overwritten.

You can [create an empty archive](https://superuser.com/q/448623/432690) ("a master archive") before the loop and then `tar -r` (instead of `tar -c`) inside the loop.

From `man 1 tar`:

> `-c`, `--create`
> Create a new archive. […]
>
> […]
>
> `-r`, `--append`
> Append files to the end of an archive. Arguments have the same meaning as for `-c` (`--create`).

Comment: I'll update the primary post with what I got in there now to verify