# tar does not do anything at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar

I have a large tar file. I'm trying to decompress it using Ubuntu Server. This is what happens:

```
ubuntu@***-***-**:~$ tar xvf myfile.tar
ubuntu@***-***-**:~$
```

The tar is not unpacked, there is no error displayed. Nothing at all. I've tried sudo and -xvf.

Comment: Does "file myfile.tar" say it looks like a tar file? Does "tar tvf myfile.tar" list its contents? After running "tar xvf myfile.tar", what does "echo $?" output?

Comment: @Spiff `file myfile.tar` returns `myfile.tar: data` . The files are not listed when I run `tar tvf myfile.tar`. After running `echo $`, the return is `0`

Comment: At the risk of mentioning a GUI, you might examine the file in Ubuntu's Archive Manager or install p7Zip (or run 7-Zip from wine). Sorry, this is not PC.

Comment: Note: an empty tar file [is just a bunch of zero bytes](https://superuser.com/a/1394368/432690). Such file is identified as `data` and extracts nothing; with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ tar ixvf myfile.tar
```

Turns out this .tar was a set of concatenated archives. From [the Documenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Ignore-Zeros.html) a block of zeros typically indicates the end of an archive, and so tar stops. When archives are concatenated, these same blocks of zeros indicate the end of one archive and the beginning of another.